# pristine HTML-Select: removing option will show selection

Tags: javascript, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I had a hard time finding a title for this question, well basically it's this:

I programmatically modify the options of an HTML-Select, and then suddenly the first options gets displayed in the select-box, although I did not click on it

Here is the complete source-code:

```js
$('#mySelect').val('');


setTimeout(function() {
  $('#333').remove();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#mySelect').val('');
  }, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form>
  <select id="mySelect">
          <option id="111" value="111">first</option>
          <option id="222" value="222">second</option>
          <option id="333" value="333">third</option>
      </select>
</form>
```

Now to clarify the situation:

I want to modify a select-dropdown based on information the user has put into other elements of a form. More specifically I want to remove certain options from a select in case they are not applicabale to the user.

But right there and then, when I remove options from a dropdown that has not yet been touched by the user, the first option of said select-dropdown will pop into view.

In order to prevent that I have to reset the value of the select-dropdown to an empty string, which I find irritating. I would expect the select-dropdown not changing it's empty state, just because I removed one of the options.

In the snippet you can see the behaviour simulated via three timeouts.

**Now the question**: I would consider the behaviour of the browser (showing the first option, although the user did not click anything) a bug. Most certainly this is not a behaviour which can be aticipated by the developer, bercause he was just removing one of the options of a previously untouched (pristine) select-dropdown? Is this a bug? Or am I just to stubborn?

Answer (score 2):

The only explanation i could provide is that this behavior happens only when you set the default value dynamically, via some jquery or JS code

(the same happens with `$('#mySelect').prop("selectedIndex", -1);` )

A workaround is to provide a hardcoded default option in your select tag, this avoids to set a blank index before and after any change :

You have the very blank type :

```
<option label=" "></option>
<option id="111" value="111">first</option>
<option id="222" value="222">second</option>
```

Or the more pleasant :

```
<option disabled selected value> Pick One...</option>
<option id="111" value="111">first</option>
<option id="222" value="222">second</option>
```